# jenkins architect support - suggestion needed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

the problem i have is i have two different teams.

**team 1** : support 800 applications
**team 2** : 400 application

i want them on jenkins , but i want to keep there jobs seperate so team 1 can only see there jobs , while team 2 can only see there jobs.

is there where i can have one jenkins instance and then two slaves ? where one slave see only team 1 applications jobs, and slave 2 sees only team 2 application jobs. ?

any suggestion to which direction i can start looking into will help. 
any plug in i can look at ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a slave will do what you want. You are trying to control who can see the jobs. You could configure certain slaves to run certain jobs, but all jobs are still viewable through master.

Take a look at the [Folders plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin). You can give each team a folder and separate access so they can only see the folder for their team.

Answer (score 1):

@adam,

Same answer to your other question.

Use [Jenkins Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin).

> This plugin adds a new role-based strategy to ease and fasten users
>   management. This strategy allows:
>
> - Creating global roles, such as admin, job creator, anonymous, etc., allowing to set Overall, Slave, Job, Run, View and SCM permissions on
>     a global basis.
> - Creating project roles, allowing to set only Job and Run permissions on a project basis.
> - Creating slave roles, allowing to set node-related permissions.
> - Assigning these roles to users.

Hope that helps.